# Regular Expression - letters, apostrophes, full stops, commas and hyphens are allowed

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, regex

I am scratching my head around for this small yet confusing requirement that I have.

I need a regular expression for the name field which only allows letters, apostrophes, full stops, commas and hyphens. Name field also should not allow more than 150 characters.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This apparently matches part of the string....^[- a-zA-Z'\.,][^/]{1,150}. But if I have numbers at the end of string like test1, it does not work.

Comment: Is allowing numbers a requirement?  You didn't specify that in the question.  What language are you using?  Can you give some example data showing what should match and what should not match?

Comment: Is `ä` a letter according to your definition?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z'.,-]{0,150}$
```

If minimum length is also required, replace `0` with such number...

Comment: Thanks....adding space works perfectly in my condition...I missed the $ at the end...which is what was making it not work for all my cases....this is what i am using now...^[a-zA-Z' .,-]{0,150}$

Comment: @user869375 - I see no space mentioned in your question, so... Anyway, good luck!

Comment: If you want to allow any unicode letter (including åöäü etc.) this might be an option for you: ^[\p{L}'.,-]{0,150}$